# Como capturar o valor do background: url('URL') usando jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<div class="chatUsers" name="chatUsers" id="1">
    <div class="chatImageUser" style="background: url('https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/2/20/LukeTLJ.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20170927034529');"></div>
    <div class="chatNomeUser">Luke Skywalker</div>
    <div class="chatStatusUser">
        <div class="chatStatusUserBall"></div>
        <div class="chatStatusUserMessage">Online</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Como eu poderia fazer para capturar o valor da `background: url('')` do elemento que tem `id=1`?

Tentei do seguinte modo, mas não deu certo:

```
var urlFoto = $("#1 > .chatImageUser").css('backgroundUrl');
```

Comment: Tente assim $('.chatImageUser').attr('style'); vou verificar uma outra forma

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Referência: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809876/can-i-get-divs-background-image-url

```js
var urlFoto = $("#1 > .chatImageUser").css('background-image'); 
urlFoto = urlFoto.replace(/.*\s?url\([\'\"]?/, '').replace(/[\'\"]?\).*/, '')
console.log(urlFoto);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chatUsers" name="chatUsers" id="1">
    <div class="chatImageUser" style="background: url('https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/2/20/LukeTLJ.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20170927034529');"></div>
    <div class="chatNomeUser">Luke Skywalker</div>
    <div class="chatStatusUser">
        <div class="chatStatusUserBall"></div>
        <div class="chatStatusUserMessage">Online</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pode ser feito da seguinte forma:

```
var urlFoto = $("#1 > .chatImageUser").css('backgroundUrl')
                                      .replace(/.*\s?url\([\'\"]?/, '')
                                      .replace(/[\'\"]?\).*/, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var chatImg = $('.chatImageUser').attr('style').split('//')[1]; 
chatImg = chatImg.replace("');",""); 
console.log(chatImg);
```